# JVM signal chaining SIGPIPE

Tags: java, c++, linux, multithreading, signals

We have a C++ application with an embedded JVM (Sun's). Because we register our own signal handlers, it's recommended we do so before initializing the JVM since it installs its own handlers ([see here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/vm/signal-chaining.html)).

From what I understood, the JVM knows internally if the signal originated from its own code and if not it passes it along the chain - to our handlers.

What we started seeing is that we're getting SIGPIPEs, with a call stack that looks roughly like this (the top entry is our signal handler):

```
/.../libos_independent_utilities.so(_ZN2os32smart_synchronous_signal_handlerEiP7siginfoPv+0x9) [0x2b124f7a3989]
/.../jvm/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so [0x2aaaab05dc6c]
/.../jvm/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so [0x2aaaab05bffb]
/.../jvm/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so(JVM_handle_linux_signal+0x718) [0x2aaaab05e878]
/.../jvm/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so [0x2aaaab05bf0e]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0 [0x3c2140e4c0]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(send+0x91) [0x3c2140d841]
/.../jvm/jre/lib/amd64/libnet.so [0x2aaabd360269]
/.../jvm/jre/lib/amd64/libnet.so(Java_java_net_SocketOutputStream_socketWrite0+0xee) [0x2aaabd35cf4e]
[0x2aaaaeb3bf7f]
```

It seems like the JVM is deciding that the SIGPIPE that was raised from `send` should be passed along to our signal hander. Is it right when doing so?

Also, why is the call stack incomplete? I mean obviously it can't show me java code before `socketWrite0` but why can't I see the stack before the java code?

Comment: Have you installed a signal handler for SIGPIPE ? (if so, yes - it's common to get SIGPIPEs from send() calls when someone writes to a broken socket )

Comment: I know that `send` can raise SIGPIPEs. I'm merely questioning the JVM's decision to pass them to me, why doesn't it raise an exception?

Comment: But you didn't install a handler for it ?

Comment: I did, otherwise my signal handler would not get called

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The JVM can't tell whether the SIGPIPE came from it's own code, or your code.  That information just isn't given by the signal.  Because it doesn't want you to miss out on any possible events that you could be interested in, it has to pass you all SIGPIPEs, even the ones that it turns out were from its own code.

Unix signals come in two flavors -- "synchronous" and "asynchronous".  A few exceptional conditions when just executing code can cause traps and result in "synchronous" signals.  These are things such as unaligned memory access (SIGBUS), illegal memory access, often NULLs, (SIGSEGV), division by zero and other math errors (SIGFPE), undecodable instructions (SIGILL), and so forth.  These have a precise execution context, and are delivered directly to the thread that caused them.  The signal handler can look up the stack and see "hey I got an illegal memory access executing java code, and the pointer was a NULL.  Let me go fix that up."

In contrast, the signals that interact with the outside world are the "asynchronous" variety, and include such things as SIGTERM, SIGQUIT, SIGUSR1, etc.  These do not have a fixed execution context.  For threaded programs they are delivered pretty much at random to any thread. Importantly, SIGPIPE is among these.  Yes, in some sense, it is normally associated with one system call.  But it is quite possible to (for instance) have two threads listening to two separate connections, both of which close before either thread is scheduled.  The kernel just makes sure that there is a SIGPIPE pending (the usual implementation is as a bitmask of pending signals), and deals with it on rescheduling any of the threads in the process.  This is only one of the simpler cases possible where the JVM might not have enough information to rule out your client code being interested in this signal.

(As to what happens to the read calls, they return "there was an error: EINTR" and continue on.  At this point, the JVM can turn that into an exception, but the return happens *after* the signal delivery and the signal handler fires.)

The upshot is you'll just have to deal with false-positives.  (And deal with getting only one signal where two might have been expected.)

Comment: then how does it know if all the other signals its registered to came from its code?

Comment: I have signal handlers for almost every signal, this is the first to show a seemingly bad behavior. Also, the JVM is registered to handle SIGPIPE, an evidence of that is the `JVM_handle_linux_signal` in the callstack - this doc also states that the JVM catches SIGPIPE http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/signals-139944.html#gbzbl There are more complex situations where the JVM simply "knows" if a signal came from its own code, e.g. the null pointer optimization, so I still don't understand your argument.

Comment: Thanks, your explanation makes sense and is more or less how I imagined the JVM making the decision whether to chain the signal or not. But still, if you look at the call stack I got in my signal handler, it's quite possible for the JVM to examine the stack and realize that the SIGPIPE originated from its own code, for example by seeing `Java_java_net_SocketOutputStream_socketWrite0` address in the call stack.

Comment: It does mean that the kernel "delivered it there".  However this really is not a guarantee that that code was the actual cause.  In this case it does happen to be, but that will not always be the case.

Comment: [SIGPIPE  may be generated synchronously in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/xrat/xbd_chap03.html)